# How I can define the limits of a bar using geom_bar() in R?

Tags: r, graph

I'd like to personalise my geom_bar() to define my superior and inferior limits for each bar. I mean, I would like to put the beginning of a bar in wherever point in my axis and its ending as the same way.

I would like to recreate this [example](http://www.marca.com/2012/03/02/multimedia/graficos/1330720526.html) using R and ggplot2.

Does someone any idea how to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please share what you've tried so far... and explain why its not working...

Something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=letters[1:10], y.min=1:10, y=11:20)
df.melt <- melt(df, id.var='x')
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=x, y=value, fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(NA,'red'))
```

Also, I assume the data visualization folks would say that this is not the right way to visualize that data...

Comment: Thanks your solution and for your recommendation :)